# How to detect RecyclerView scroll due to bottom-most item height decrease?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

### The Situation

A `RecyclerView` has a `OnScrollListener` that provides a callback when it is being scrolled, either manually or programmatically.

However, I found that it misses one scenario - When the `RecyclerView`'s bottom item's height decreases.

It may be hard to imagine by just a few words, let me give you an example:
I have a `RecyclerView` that consists of some **expandable** items. When user collapses an expanded item, the item view height will decrease.
Now, imagine user is looking at an expanded item at the bottom, and `RecyclerView` is scrolled to the bottom as well.  If user now collapses the item, `RecyclerView` will adjust its contents' position so that *the bottom of the bottom-most item always touches the bottom of `RecyclewView`*.
The situation can be illustrated in the below image:

[image: Image Demo]

### The Question

Actually, I have to listen to this `RecyclerView`'s scroll event to adjust some view elements (e.g. A top floating bar on top of it). But since the "scroll" due to such item height change does not trigger the `OnScrollListener`, how should I listen to this scroll in other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with an alternative, though worked very well.

First of all, I am using [this library](https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout) for Expandable Item.
This library has a callback when the state of the expansion status updates, including:

- Expanded,
- Expanding,
- Collapsing,
- Collapsed.

Since this situation only happens for the collapsing of last item, so what I did is:

1. First check if the item is the last item
2. Check if the status is collapsing
3. Memorize the top position of the last item when it starts to collapse
4. Manually trigger RecyclerView's `onScroll` by calculating the difference between existing top position and memorized top position.

All of the above is trying to simulate `onScroll` of RecyclerView. Luckily it turns out worked perfectly.

Code Snippet: (Inside `ExpandableLayout`'s `onExpansionUpdateListener`)

```
if (state == ExpandableLayout.State.COLLAPSING) {
    if (lastItemTopPosition == null) {
        lastItemTopPosition = itemView.getTop();
    } else {
        if (getAdapterPosition()+1 == getItemCount()) { //The last item
            recyclerViewCompounded.onScroll(0, lastItemTopPosition - itemView.getTop());
            lastItemTopPosition = itemView.getTop();
        }
    }
} else if (state == ExpandableLayout.State.COLLAPSED) {
    lastItemTopPosition = null;
}
```